# Cannot create rule to match event that is sent manually to the event bus but the pattern is identical

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to understand the AWS EventBridge better.

I've sent an event manually through the console that was confirmed:
[image]

Then I tried to create a rule for the same event bus to catch that event when I hit "Resend" (in the picture above).

However, I get stuck at creating the rule.

As sample event (I know this is optional, but still) I copy-pasted the event that I sent manually:
[image]

And as matching rule I copy-pasted the same, which, I think, should just work as it appears that this is exactly the event that I would be sending manually (see first picture above). <--- Wrong assumption?

But I get an error:
[image]

There is a blind spot in my understanding, but I don't see it, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`version must be an object or an array` you need to enclose version value in `[]`. E.g. `”version”: [“0”]`

**Edit:**

This is not just for the `version` in your example. All values within the pattern should be an object.

E.g.:
[image]

Comment: +1 on what Tsal said. In addition, I recommend starting with a simple pattern and then iterate through as the UI pattern matcher passes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments ... that is indeed what the message says. I just don't understand why the console seems to manage to send a message that is not an "object", just a string (first screenshot "confirmation"), and if I copy-paste that same message ... it is rejected! ... Isn't that odd?